# Glassfish 3: 3rd party jar not logging to server.log via java.util.logger

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I'm using a 3rd party jar within my web app that uses standard java.util.logging for writing log messages. Thus it should work with the GF standard log and the logging in my app, as both are too using java.util.logging.

I've added the logger of the third party jar (com.xyz...) in the Glassfish admin console and set the desired log level. But nevertheless no messages from the 3rd party jar are showing up in the server.log.

Any hints how to overcome this? Or should I switch to slf4j with logback?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the loglevel for `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler` also to the same log level as of the 3rd party jar...